# What is the corrispettive motion convention for robotic systems with X,Y,Z axis?

Tags: design

We built several systems coupling multiple linear micrometric stages. I can't find a standard defining the axis convention of these kinds of systems, it there are any.

[image]

Regarding the system on the left, I would say that is an XZ system while I would define the system on the right XY system. However, I can't find any standard where this convention is explicitly stated.
For us, this is very important because we want to define univocally the various categories that we developed.
Is there any ISO standard? Or best practice I can use as reference this convention?

Comment: I don't get your question, of course it depends on how you put the reference coordinate system or perhaps the manufacturer should state that with the reference system they are using.

Comment: @jdios my question is about finding a common nomenclature for the systems that we are developing. Like the Z axis always point upward etc. etc.

Comment: I do not have the knowledge if there exist any standard for these systems. But in any case you can define your own definitions for this, since you are the manufacturer. Just remember to keep the orthogonality and directions of the standard XYZ reference system.